# Solution of Time Independent Schrodinger Equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, scattering

In the book Modern Physics by Serway/Moses/Moyer (on page 200,chapter Quantum mechanics in one dimension) it is written that (or what i have understood)when there are no forces on a particle solution of schrodinger equation in separable form is identical to that of a plane wave. But the wavefunction associated with a particle has to be confined to a region. Then how it is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time-independent Schrödinger equation for a free particle
(i.e. with a potential energy $U(x)=0$)
$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2\psi(x)}{d x^2}=E\psi(x)$$
has indeed the solutions
$$\psi(x) = Ae^{ikx} \quad\text{with any real }k$$
for the energy $E=\frac{\hbar^2k^2}{2m}$,
as can easily be verified.
Obviously these solutions are not localized in space.
Instead they are evenly spread across the whole space
from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$.

A stringent mathematician might complain, that these solutions
cannot be normalized to $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|\psi(x)|^2 dx=1$.
But for a pragmatic physicist this is no problem.
Such a solution just represents a particle moving with a perfectly
certain momentum $p=\hbar k$ (thus $\Delta p=0$).
Therefore, according to Heisenberg's uncertainty principle,
it has a completely uncertain position $x$ (i.e. $\Delta x=\infty$).

Comment: Also, if it is confined to a region, that can just be taken to be the (infinite) square well potential, which then gives us momentum-like eigenstates in a box.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I disagree. In an (infinite) square well potential
we have solutions like $A\cos(kx)$ or $A\sin(kx)$  (for certain $k$ values).
But these are *not* momentum eigenstates, since they are superpositions of
$e^{ikx}$ *and* $e^{−ikx}$ together.

Comment: Hence the -like.